# Changing the display image of an imageview based on the data in a string (Such as word)

Tags: android, android-studio

Going to briefly explain what's going on. I want to update a single imageView to change it to differently named drawable images. There is only four choices here, this is because i'm bringing data from a spinner, which has a choice of 4 countries, selected from another activity. This then changes the imageView to the custom drawable image of said country.

So far i'm unsure how i'm going to do this, tried a few very basic if else statements but they are very incorrect.

I'll post some of what I have below:

```
public class WorldImage extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textCountry;

    private String stringCountry;

    ImageView imageCountry;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_worldimage);

        Intent aIntent = getIntent();
        stringCountry = aIntent.getStringExtra("movetoImageActivity");

        textCountry= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.movetoviewCountry);
        imageCountry = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageCountry);
```

It's around here I get lost, some really basic if & else if statements, such as:

```
        if (textCountry.getText().toString().equals("Europian Union"))
{
    imageCountry.setImageResource(R.drawable.eu_flag);
}
```

What would be reccomended here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about printing log?

```
    Intent aIntent = getIntent();
    stringCountry = aIntent.getStringExtra("movetoImageActivity");

    textCountry= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.movetoviewCountry);
    imageCountry = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageCountry);



    Log.e("TEST", "stringCountry : " + stringCountry );
    Log.e("TEST", "textCountry: " + textCountry.getText().toString());

    if (stringCountry.equals("Europian Union")){
       Log.e("TEST", "Europian Union");
       imageCountry.setImageResource(R.drawable.eu_flag);
    }else   if (stringCountry.equals("Something else")){
       Log.e("TEST", "Something else");
       imageCountry.setImageResource(R.drawable.something);
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem to work either, crashes without even giving an debug error

Comment: Ok, this does in-fact work, and quite well, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a switch statement like this:

```
switch(stringCountry){
    case "Europian Union":
          imageCountry.setImageResource(R.drawable.eu_flag);
          break;
    case "United States":
          imageCountry.setImageResource(R.drawable.us_flag);
          break;
    default: 
          // optional. Use if all comparisons above fail and you want to handle it
         break;
}
```